# tried doing an iteration thread sleep to make a little animation thingy

Tags: java, string

```
import java.util.*;

public class StrngBufr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a1="Enter a Sentence";
        func(a1);

        String a2 = "Enter another Sentence";
        func(a2);

    }
        void func( String a )

     {
         char[] strng = a.toCharArray();
         try {
         for(char i : strng ) {
             System.out.println(i);
             Thread.sleep(70);
         }
         }
         catch (Exception e) {}


    }

}
```

Here's the code....

im new to this stuff ... I cant seem to find what's wrong..

These are the Errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method func(String) is undefined for the type StrngBufr
    The method func(String) is undefined for the type StrngBufr
    void is an invalid type for the variable func
    Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
```

Comment: And your question is..? Please format your code properly.

Comment: You should use an IDE. func has to be static.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. here is a link on how to ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please try to *ask a question*. that being said, the error is pretty self explanatory - you have a method named 'func' that is not defined..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance of `StrngBufr` to call the function, or just declare it `static`.

Answer (score 0):

While you seem new to coding, I highly recommend you to use an IDE to get started, otherwise you will run into errors you don't understand and it's a great help for beginners.

Basically, the function `func` is not `static` and therefore cannot be referenced from a static context. In order for it to work you can either:

```
static void func(String a)
```

or create a new instance of `StrngBufr`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    StrngBufr bufr = new StrngBufr();
    String a1="Enter a Sentence";
    bufr.func(a1);

    String a2 = "Enter another Sentence";
    bufr.func(a2);
}
```

Some words: Give your variables and classes decent name. Your class isn't even a StringBuffer, but something else. Also, you don't need to convert your `String` into a `char[]` in order to iterate over it. The `String` class has several functions like `length()` and `charAt()` ;)

This is how Eclipse would have helped you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time.. (although it's 2 years late)...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an **instance method** `void func(String a)`. Doing this will need an *instance* of the class containing this function. So either create instance of `StrngBufr` inside main function and then call func from that or simply define `func` as `static function` (**class method**) to use is directly.